# Executing api in while loop, gives 500 internal server error

Tags: php, api, curl

I am executing someapi with curl, in a while loop. If i don't execute the api and just echo what api is executing, the output is fine... if i execute that api, lets say 1000 times in a while loop.. it gives 500 Internal Server Error in half way.

i want that api should be executed one after one (synchronous), if it get any error, it should ignore it and continue.

this is my code:

```
while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($allDetail)){
    $resulter = myCurl($res['var1'],$res['var2']);
}

function myCurl($var1,$var2){
            $ch = curl_init('some_api_url_with_var1_var2');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
}
```

this is first time i am using curl, and i am also new to php.
the api returns true or whatever error is in json format, but i don't want to care for it, just the api keeps on executing

Comment: Is that your server that returns HTTP 500? Probably you are using (fast)cgi, the script terminated because of a time limit, apache does not receive the response, so on. Check for "premature end of script headers" in the error log - if there is, this is the case

Comment: 500 is due to memory usage, can you help me with this ??

Comment: You may refer this link `http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-init.php` , for multiple curl request calling instead of loops.

Answer (score 3):

HTTP errors are divided into classes:

- 2xx are success messages
- 3xx are redirect messages
- 4xx are client error messages
- 5xx are server error messages

A "500 Internal Server Error" is an error on the API you're hitting. You're probably hitting them too fast and they can't handle that. If the API is yours, try debugging what's going on there. For example, Apache automatically sends 500 when PHP emits a Fatal Error (memory usage or timeouts can lead to Fatal Errors). Other languages have similar behavior.

Try a `sleep(1)` on each iteration on the while loop. The code should run slower, but if anything goes well, it means that before you were hitting them too hard. There is also a `usleep()` function for sleeping in milliseconds instead of seconds.

Curl has an `CURLOPT_FAILONERROR` option. When this is set to true, it ignores errors. Should help if you want to continue looping even on request failure. The `curl_error()` function can also be useful.

Comment: its not my api, and its 100% bug free..
its basically coz of memory usage.. how can i make it work on the server that it should use less memory and work fast.. any solution?
the sleep function didnt helped

Comment: You should contact the guys from the API and ask them what's going on. 500 are server errors, not yours.